# how to get docker api version by SDK of Golang?

Tags: docker, go

I need to know Docker Daemon API version and setup the environment variable of `DOCKER_API_VERSION` when I have to create Docker client with [NewEnvClient()](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#NewEnvClient), if not I will get an error about:

```
Error response from daemon: client version 1.36 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.35
```

Comment: Are you executing your go code in the same docker host which you expect to execute docker commands?

Comment: Unfortunately, my code executing on other hosts that I can't execute `docker version`

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing your code in the same docker host you can use the following approach to get the API version. It execute `docker version` command and get the API version from that output.

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("docker", "version", "--format", "{{.Server.APIVersion}}")
    cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
    cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    apiVersion := strings.TrimSpace(string(cmdOutput.Bytes()))
    // TODO: (optional) verify the api version is in the correct format(a.b)
    os.Setenv("DOCKER_API_VERSION", apiVersion)
    // execute docker commands
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = cli.ImagePull(ctx, "alpine", types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but it does not suit me, my code executing on another host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClientVersion](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ClientVersion) function call to get the version, Whereas its better to negotiate the api version by using client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation() in [NewClientWithOpts](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#NewClientWithOpts).
In case you are interested in making a direct API call from your local you can use below command, it can give you much more details then api version.

```
curl  --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://localhost/version" -H "X-Registry-Auth:<encoded key>" | jq '.ApiVersion'
"1.41"
```